# Do method variables need to be released?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

In Objective-C, if I have a method

```
-(IBAction) didTouchSomething:(id)sender {
  NSString* test = [DataGetter read];

  if(test == nil) {
    do something
  }
}
```

Do I need to release test, or do anything else to it memory-wise?  Or is it automatically handled when the method finishes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to release things you own via alloc, copy, new or retain. Check Apples "[Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)". Very clear and helpful.

The pointer you create does not need to released, anyways. Only the object it might point to, but then only in the cases stated above.

Answer (score 2):

### In principle:

You are not calling a method with a name containing "copy", "alloc", "new" or "get" (*CANG*) — so you **must not** release `test`, because you don't *own* it.

### In practice:

Ensure that `+[DataGetter read]` returns an `autorelease`d object.

Example:

```
+(NSString *)read
{
   NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Homedir: %@", [@"~" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];
   return result;  // Correct: You don't own "result", so you can return it as is
}
// Alternate implementation 1:
+(NSString *)read
{
   NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Homedir: %@", [@"~" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];
   return result; // Wrong: You own "result" since you created it!
}
// Alternate implementation 2:
+(NSString *)read
{
   NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Homedir: %@", [@"~" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];
   return [result autorelease]; // Correct: calling autorelease ensures that result is going to be released later on.
}
```